# Is it possible to write a Spark SQL query to insert catalog (e.g "create catalog x")?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

is there any query such as "create catalog x" ? I didn't find it on the documentation here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Catalog is a spark abstraction to control metadata. It has several implementations: hive or in-memory. And it will be automatically created by spark.

You can control which implementation is using with **spark.sql.catalogImplementation** or with `SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport`(which set spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive)

If you're using hive as catalog implementation, there're several ways how hive can work, you can read about these more [here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-hive-metastore/) .